# Using Firebase as a scheduler

Tags: firebase, push-notification, cron, scheduler

2 years back, I was tasked to quickly build a system for an Health Club that was hit by the Covid pandemic. The system was built within a week & I used what technology I was comfortable with and deployed the system.

The requirements were simple - A member subscribes to a program and he gets regular, timely notifications via FCM. The signup date of the member is rolling, hence it has to follow the n+number of days & time schedule logic.

I built this using simple php with nodejs handling the scheduler. The scheduler runs every minute, checks the mariadb database and runs a loop to send these notifications. *This is running correctly at the moment.* Having said this, I know this is not the optimal way of doing a solution like this.

I would compare this to the "Autoresponders" we set in any mailing system. Once a person joins, we can schedule Autoresponders - the sending and delivery is managed by the mailing provider.

I wanted to understand if I can use Topics or Realtime / Firebase database to achieve this?

I know it's a super generic question, but if someone can point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Regards,
Mihir.
PS: I am insisting on Firebase because my apps are already integrated with it and would not require much of work to run these changes.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but if you want to do but if you want to run something periodically you can use [Scheduled Firebase Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions)

Comment: Yes, it's a super generic question. The simple answer is; yes, that can (easily) be done with Firebase - both the Realtime Database and Firestore. Not sure how helpful that is though or what kind of answer you would need other than that. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)